# Running "configure.file" for TCL/TK memory debugging on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: tcl

I am attempting to enable memory debugging using [the wiki](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/TCL_MEM_DEBUG.htm), and I am not sure how to do the following step:

> e.g. by passing the --enable-symbols=mem flag to the configure script when building

I am not sure how to do this for a .FILE extension.

Furthermore, after this is done, does `#define TCL_MEM_DEBUG` need to be in `TclInt.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood it right by reading the comments at the top of `win\makefile.vc`, on Windows you enable memory debugging by passing `STATS=memdbg` to `nmake` (or by passing the right options `win\configure` if you're using a non-Microsoft toolchain):

```
cd tcl\win
nmake -f makefile.vc install STATS=memdbg
```

I emphasise that I've *never* tried this.